# Why is printf causing a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, environment-variables, printf, c-strings

I have this code:

```
char* env;

if (getenv("MP") == NULL)
{
    env = "/usr";
}
else
{
    env = getenv("MP");
}

printf("($MP is %s)\n", env);
printf("The program seg faults without printing me :(");
```

The program appears to seg fault after the first print if the $MP environmental variable is not set. If it is set, there is no seg fault and everything works fine.

Comment: This code runs fine for me, you're logic is a little bit strange tho ;)

Comment: Use `valgrind` or `gdb` to find the exact position in your code where it segfaults.

Comment: I was mistaken, the second print doesn't print because I forgot to end the line, whoops, gdb showed me that.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem was with code not related to that shared here.

Answer (score 3):

I can get your program to segfault if I don't include `stdlib.h`

I.e. try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char* env;

    if (getenv("MP") == NULL)
    {
        env = "/usr";
    }
    else
    {
        env = getenv("MP");
    }

    printf("($MP is %s)\n", env);
    printf("The program seg faults without printing me :(");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah, i included stdlib.h when testing by default. That's quite interesting.

Comment: Confirmed :) Crashes only when the MP environment variable is set tho.

Comment: I had to look into this after my first idiotic answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do this?

```
const char *env = getenv("MP");
if (!env)
    env = "/usr";
```

Comment: That's basically what I did have before I tried all sorts of other whacky things to see if any would work :P